# Ask for compensation mark for the distinction degree

Tags: masters, gpa

I am finishing my master degree in the UK. To gain an MSC with Distinction at my Uni, there are 2 requirements:

- Credit weighted averaged (CWA) at least 70% on all classes with no failed
- Thesis should normally achieve a mark of at least 65%

Currently, my CWA is 69, and my thesis is 70. It means I am 1% away from the distinction mark. I really want to get the distinction at the current status, and I want to polish my application to the PhD program. I am thinking of asking the department for compensation in the board meeting to gain the distinction. Is it a good idea? If yes, what should I write/say so that it doesn't seem unethical? If not, are there other solutions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So,  you want to be given something that you haven’t earned? Why would the board agree to such a request?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how an ask can be unethical, no matter what you say so long as you are polite.

Whether it would be granted or not depends on how strictly the rules are followed in general.

If possible, explore whether other slight adjustments have ever been allowed in the past or not. As for other solutions, you could ask someone with authority in the department. Perhaps even your advisor can give advice.